# How to set custom Icon on Custom Activity Designer in Workflow Foundation?

Tags: workflow-foundation, activitydesigner, workflow-rehosting

I am Re-Hosting the Workflow Foundation of .NET Framework. And I have a **custom** `Activity`. I tried to point out the key points of my **folder architecture** as well as the **icon properties**.

What I want is to display a custom icon on my custom activity.
But when I run the app I'm getting this error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '9' and line position '5'.'
```

I believe I'm setting the URL incorrectly somehow but I tried many variations I could find on the internet and still could not get it to work.

[image]

I'm hoping the image here shed some light on my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this below did the trick:

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner.Icon>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <ImageDrawing>
                    <ImageDrawing.Rect>
                        <Rect Location="0,0" Size="16,16" ></Rect>
                    </ImageDrawing.Rect>
                    <ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Wpf.MainApp;component/Assets/Icons/icons8-data-grid-96.png"></BitmapImage>
                    </ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
                </ImageDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </sap:ActivityDesigner.Icon>
```